# How do I get the correct object variable names in the grandCouncil array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, push

When I console.log(grandCouncil) I end up getting this:

```
[Object, Object, Object]
```

What I want to see is the names of the variables instead likes this:

```
[jungleAnimal1, jungleAnimal2, jungleAnimal3]
```

Here is my code:

```
var grandCouncil = [];


var jungleAnimal1 = {
  'type': "frog",
  'collects': ['flys','moths','beetles'],
  'canFly': false
};

var jungleAnimal2 = {
  'type': "jaguar",
  'collects': ['wild pigs','deer','sloths'],
  'canFly': false
};

var jungleAnimal3 = {
  'type': "parrot",
  'collects': ['fruits','bugs','seeds'],
  'canFly': true
};

grandCouncil.push(jungleAnimal1,jungleAnimal2,jungleAnimal3);
console.log(grandCouncil);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jungleAnimal1,2 and 3 are object literals.

When you push them into the grandCouncil array, references to those objects are added to the array, but the variable names are not.

If you want to use jungleAnimal1,2 and 3 as *properties* under grandCouncil, grandCouncil should be an object and the animals can be properties, like so:

```
grandCouncil = {
    "jungleAnimal1" : { // type, collects, canFly }
    "jungleAnimal2" : ...
    "jungleAnimal3" : ...
}
```

Thank you @zerkms for the clarification

Comment: "the object values are added to the array" --- I would say the references to objects are added.

Answer (score 0):

The values stored in the array are Objects; for example, you can access the values of the object by using dot notation, so to access jungleAnimal2's type would simply be:

```
grandCouncil[1].type
```

You could

```
for(var i = 0;i < grandCouncil.length; i++){
    for(animal in grandCouncil[i]){
        console.log(animal);   
    }
}
```

This is simply iterating over each array element, which is an object, and then iterating through each element in those objects. You can access specific properties by using the aforementioned dot notation, so to console.log all types, just do `animal.type`.

Comment: the main objective that I've been given is to some how after creating jungleAnimal1, jungleAnimal2, jungleAnimal3 to push all of that info into the empty array of grandCouncil. Any more suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I'm sorta confused as to what the main goal is, because you have references to each object in the array.